# How to use CONTAINS in SOQl Query

Tags: apex, soql, contains

My SOQL Query

```
 string str = '%'+email.subject.trim()+'%';
  GMC__c gmcList =  [select id,name,Case_Number__c from GMC__c where name like :str limit 1];
```

GMC__c Name is an autonumber field which will be unique

Now my actual requirement is when a user sends mail Subject with only Name it works perfect. In the other case if he sends say suppose **This is regarding GMCName** then we need to Query that contains GMCName. What would be the best aproach for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood from your requirement is, `Subject` sent by User can be dynamic. Sometimes its only `GMCName` and sometimes it is included in some sentence, as you have mentioned `This is regarding GMCName`. 
 And your `GMC__c Name` is `autonumber` field. So it must be having some particular format like `Q{00000}` i.e `A-{0000}` etc. Having fixed length and fixed format. You must be knowing starting characters of your `GMC Name`. 
You can do following :

`Integer index = email.subject.indexOf(--Starting Characters of GMC Name--);`

//As you know length of your GMC name(as it is Autonumber), so that length to `Integer index` obtained above.

`String gmcName = email.subject.substring(index,index+lengthOfAutonumber)`
In this way you can obtain GMCName

Answer (score 1):

I need to query the Email Template's Name and FolderName with Subject 'Application Finalised'

But I am getting the error ' Subject cannot be filtered in a query call '. Can someone help me in this please.

I did this->
select Id, Name, Subject, FolderName from EmailTemplate where Subject Like '%Application Finalised%'

Comment: Hello Revanth, if you have a new question, I suggest you to post a new question instead of posting as an answer in an old question.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/166820)